# replace NAs with division of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that looks like:

```
a   b  c   d
1   2  NA  1
NA  2  2   1 
3   2  NA  1
NA  NA 20  2
```

And I want to replace the NAs with `c / d` (and delete `c` and `d`) to look like:

```
a  b
1  2
2  2
3  2
10 10
```

Some background: `d` is a sum of `NA`s in that particular row.

I don't know the names of the columns, so I tried a few variations of things like:

```
df2[, 1:(length(colnames(df2)) - 2)][is.na(df2[, 1:(length(colnames(df2)) - 2)])] = df2$c / df2$d
```

but got:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df2[, 1:(length(colnames(df2)) -  : 
  'value' is the wrong length
```

Comment: You have to use the same indexing to the right of the equals sign as you do on the left of the equals sign -- you're not indicating *which* c and *which* d you want.

Comment: must've been a copy, paste mistake. It should be `df2$c / df2$d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
data<-fread("a   b  c   d
1   2  NA  1
            NA  2  2   1 
            3   2  NA  1
            NA  NA 20  2")
names_to_loop<-names(data)
names_to_loop<-names_to_loop[names_to_loop!="c"&names_to_loop!="d"]
for (ntl in names_to_loop){
  set(data,j=ntl,value=ifelse(is.na(data[[ntl]]),data[["c"]]/data[["d"]],data[[ntl]]))
}
data[,c:=NULL]
data[,d:=NULL]
> data
    a  b
1:  1  2
2:  2  2
3:  3  2
4: 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do this with [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/).

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  a = c(1, NA, 3, NA),
  b = c(2, 2, 2, NA),
  c = c(NA, 2, NA, 20L),
  d = c(1, 1, 1, 2)
)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-c, -d), funs(if_else(is.na(.), c / d, .))) %>% 
  select(-c, -d)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     3     2
#> 4    10    10
```

You can specify the variables in the `vars()` call using any of the functions from `?dplyr::select_helpers`. These could be regex, a simple vector of names, or you can just use all columns except `c` and `d` (as I've changed this example to now).

Comment: the only issue is I don't know the column names, except for `c` and `d`

Comment: Hi, I added solution which does not depend on whether you know the names of the columns or not!

Comment: where? isn't `vars(a, b)` refering to columns `a` and `b`?. I might add, I also don't know how many columns there are.

Comment: @RafaelMartins I updated the example so you don't need to know what variable names in advance. You can just use all except `c` and `d`